# Inserting html tags on image at specific positions in html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, png

I have this image Map.png. i want to write text these location boxes using html.
so that i can change it dynamically.
I just do not know how to that.. please give me a direction.
[image]

Comment: You write code. That's YOUR job. This is not a code writing service, or "do my job for me", or "teach me how to do my job". YOU write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this.

1. Simplistic way would be using just css absolute property and top/left properties to position the location icons on top of the map.png. Add the map.png to a div and make the div css position relative. Add each location icon at top/left property and make sure location icon css position is absolute.
2. Better way would be to use [Google Map Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Draw the polygons for the states in you map.png on top of the Google map and then position Google location markers. Much slicker and very easy to use.